# Selective syncing with Google?

Tags: sync, google

By default if you sync with Google, contacts, calendar, app data and wifi keys are synchronized. Is it possible to synchronize only some of these things, e.g. only calendar and contacts? Thanks :-)

Comment: Please see your other question on the topic: [What exactly is synced with Google?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30346/what-exactly-is-synced-with-google).

Comment: I think this is different.  The other question is about backup, this one is about sync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System Settings` -> `Accounts & sync` ->  Select your google account -> Make use of the checkboxes.

[image: sync settings]
<sup>sync settings (click for larger image)</sup>

Comment: If the checkboxes aren't visible, it's likely because you have sync disabled completely.

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely correct. Will not see the checkboxes if sync is off.