# What exactly is synced with Google?

Tags: sync, google, cloud

If you enable syncing to Google, what exactly is synced in a more technical way? E.g. about syncing app data, I guess there is just one standard path synchronized? Has anyone seen a more technical documentation of the synching, that describes, what exactly is synchronized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard) is a service for accessing a simple view of the data associated with a Google account. With Dashboard you can also get a list of your Android apps that store data in the Google cloud, the dates of their latest backups, the amount of storage they use, and some additional data such as the date you first registered the device. To access this information:

1. visit Google Dashboard at https://www.google.com/dashboard
2. enter your Google username and password, and log in
3. scroll down to section "Android devices"
4. click the "More data stored about this device" link under your
   device names's entry

Answer (score 7):

You can check this e.g. in the [Honeycomb User Guide](http://www.google.com/help/hc/pdfs/mobile/AndroidUsersGuide-30-100.pdf). Basically, it sums up to the following:

- Android Settings, as WiFi networks incl. passwords, user dictionary, etc.
- Settings of many Google apps, as e.g. browser favorites
- Apps downloaded from the Playstore

Additionally, app developers *can* use this API to have their apps data backup'd along -- but only few do so. Furthermore I wouldn't rely on this backup -- there are many reports that, while the backup works, the restore not always does: It seems there's no way to manually trigger it, and on initialization after e.g. a factory reset (or with a new device) it often fails. also, as far as I know, it's an all-or-nothing thing: You can have it let all your backed-up data restore (as described before), or not.