# How does one copy all the data AND apps from one Asus tablet to another?

Tags: backup, asus-eee-pad-transformer, asus-transformer-infinity

I have an Asus Transformer Prime TF-201, and am upgrading to an Asus Transformer Pad Infinity TF-701. Before I sell my old table, I want to backup all my data and apps, and somehow transfer them to the new tablet. Is this possible *without* rooting the tablet? Both are currently synced with my Google account, and on both tablets, under **Settings**->**Backup and Restore**, both tablets are set to backup information to Google.

Comment: For the "Backup and Restore" you are referring to, please see [What exactly is synced with Google?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30346/what-exactly-is-synced-with-google/30348#30348) -- it's much less than you'd expect. Especially it's not "all your apps data".

Comment: Thank you, that does explain why nothing else transferred... Except it didn't save my Asus settings either :( Oh well. I'm going to try the solutions below too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could start with the very same lamentations: No root no fun. As except for root only the app itself can access its data, there's no real way around -- except...

But first an elegant alternative to the mentioned [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup): While running both (rooted!) devices simultaneously, 
[AppSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrulri.appsync) can synchronize apps and data. So you could even start some game on one device, sync, and continue on the other -- just to give you one example.

[image: AppSync]

The one possibility without root requires at least ICS (Android 4.x). I'm not sure whether this works betwenn different devices (or whether some device component is used for encryption), but as far as I understood it should do: Using `adb backup` and `adb restore`, which requires the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installed on your computer, and is described in detail in the article on [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices).

Answer (score 1):

I know you would like to have the transfer done without rooting.  But in my opinion it can't be done. So, in case if you are ready for a compromise on rooting, you can use Titanium Backup Root app to back up and restore apps with its data and settings.

I once did this kind of transfer between two rooted phones. On the first phone, I backed up all user apps with its settings and data. I copied the TB's folder in SD card to my computer and in my other phone (already rooted) I used the same Google account and downloaded Titanium Backup. After a first run, I copied the previously copied TB's folders from computer to the other phone's SD card, over writing the existing content. After running TB in the other phone, I opted for restore all user apps with its data and I got back everything as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have news for whomever said: "Without root it's not possible" yes it is. I got a Asus transformer TF700T in Oct 12. It came with app backup. It gives you the choice of just backing up the app or app/data. Tested it and it works!

Comment: The fact is not new (see: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/16575)). But that an app for this comes pre-installed on some devices means somebody with "root" did so, and arranged the required privileges. This might be specific to that manufacturer, or even to this device line (here: it might be the case for the TF700T as shipped when you purchased yours, but not for previous versions or other product lines as e.g. the TF-201).

Answer (score 0):

What about [FruitMobile App BackUp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fruitmobile.app.backup)? I haven't tested it but it looks like it can backup/restore apps and app data to/from the SD card without root.

Comment: Checked the play store and www.fruitmobile.com: No where it is mentioned that data will be backed up. Emphasis on root privilege is required especially to read the data and not for extracting the APK for the apps. Can only ensure by using it.

Comment: Right. It backs up the APK only. My mistake.

Comment: You are only trying to help :) I had sent an email to the developer seeking clarification. I am yet to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, this is not possible without rooting.  Application data and settings can't be accessed outside the application/system by the regular user account for security reasons.

Comment: Sorry Logos, but "not possible without rooting" is simply wrong -- except if you limit it to "prior ICS (Android 4.0)". See my answer and follow the link for details (or just follow the link in the "Linked" section of this question).

Comment: I did say it was a short answer.  I'm taking into consideration the fact that any user who stipulates non-root solutions likely isn't going to be capable of installing and using ADB effectively - particularly as transferring settings (which I assume is included under 'data') between two different devices is problematic even for the extremely savvy.

Comment: OK, so let's agree on "is difficult without rooting" :)