# Google account not saving Wifi passwords, apps, etc

Tags: sync, google-account

My favorite part about Android is how Google backups almost everything for you without you actually really noticing. I just got a Nexus 5 and logged in to my Google account right away. I noticed it did not start installing all my apps right away and now when I go over to friends' houses their wifi passwords aren't saved from before. This is really annoying cause they all have default router passwords that are extremely long.

I installed a few ROMs just to play around with the phone, and each time I did the initial setup and signed in to Google, it would not sync anything...

I have "Back up my data, Backup account, Automatic restore" all set in settings.
Any ideas why this is happening to my Google account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a pretty well known "feature". Don't worry, your data *is* backed up there – it only does not *restore*. And you cannot even really delete it there. So in some way, it's "safe"...

Things you might want to look up in this context:

- **[What exactly is synced with Google?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30346/16575)**
  Underlines what I've said before, and also shows you ways to check what's "synced"
- **[Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575)**
  Plenty of details on how that "Google Cloud Backup" works (and sometimes fails)
- **[What info does Google backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15434/16575)**
  Well, the title says it all :)
- **[Issue 17354: "Automatic Restore" rarely works, and then only partially](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17354)**
  What I already indicated above, and most likely the answer to your current issue. Note that this ticket was opened in June, 2011 – and still has the status "New". One of the comments also includes a possible work-around:

  > Here's what I did that worked. I factory reset the device (again), and then at the very first screen (where you choose the language), I turn it off. I put in a difference sim card, turn it on and then proceed with the normal setup. This worked for my Nexus 4.
- **[Heise on undeletable WiFi Passwords](http://www.heise.de/-1922971.html)** (German)
  If you don't believe me about "undeletable backups", this is my reference. The article is in German, and the publisher (Heise Verlag) is one of the most famous and most trusted sources here in Germany, concerning IT topics.

There are many many more references I could give, but that would be a bit much for here. So a last hint: check the "Linked" and "Related" question links on the ASE Q&As I've linked here.

Comment: Link to the google issue made me happy. I couldn't find it. I have been having this problem since then too. I guess google is ignoring it? Maybe only a few accounts have the issue. Thanks anyways

Comment: Indeed it doesn't affect everybody (for different reasons: it doesn't affect me since I don't trust Google with all my data, and thus do not use the "Cloud Backup" – and others are happily using it without ever having the trouble, though), or Google would have long reacted. Similarly with the device manager: I cannot locate any of my devices with it (Android 2.3/4.0/4.1), and many others neither. It seems to work for the majority (80%+). // Did the described SIM-trick work for you? Have you been able to "restore all"?