# Lost Device = WiFi Passwords and Backup Data Stored Permanently on Google

Tags: backup, google-backup

Various sites like [BGR](http://bgr.com/2013/09/13/google-android-wi-fi-passwords/) have written articles on [How to remove data from Google's backup and restore cloud](http://bgr.com/2013/09/13/google-android-wi-fi-passwords/).

But it's not possible once you've lost access to the device.  Hence your data will remain with Google FOREVER.

It looks like Android's Backup and Restore option makes it impossible to delete data stored on once the user no longer has access to the device.

[image: Android Backup and Restore Menu]

According to the Answer in:

[Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49425)

Backups are stored in sets:

Example: 
[Device serial][ Google Email] : 
[3f0e5c90a412cca7] [ sampleemail@gmail.com]

and "You can't make a device start writing into a different set, nor can you wipe a whole set."

Since this is the case, once you lose access to your device, even with your email logged in from a different device, since you no longer have access to the device with the right serial, you no longer have the ability to delete the set from the Backup & Restore menu.

I checked to see if unchecking the "Back up my data" from one device would also uncheck the option across all devices using the same account for backup.

Apparently, this option in the other devices remained checked suggesting that their backup sets remained intact and continue to backup.

Is there a way to delete the backup data set once the device is inaccessible to the user?

Comment: According to a (German) [article on Heise](http://www.heise.de/-1922971.html), it's not possible at all to delete what Google once got. I've just summed up a few more related information [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58842/16575) a couple of minutes ago, if you want to check.

Comment: @JeffreyLin The objective of this post is regarding the deletion of personal data on Google's servers not on the device itself.